# how to read and write to a filesystem in linux?

Tags: filesystems

I have a hard disk and partitioned it into several partitions. How can i read and write into the filesystem. What is the use of mountpoint? If a process has to write or read something from that partition, should it write to the mount point which in turn will take care of writing to the disk?

Answer (score 2):

You have several deviced that are logically organized under the `/dev` directory, for harddisks (e.g.) `/dev/sda`, or partitions like `/dev/sda1`. In Unix those individual devices are mapped into a filesystem hierarchy; all starts with a root directory `/`, and under that are the subdirectories. To map the individual devices into that hierarchy you `mount` it; for example a **mountpoint** `/home/tom` (initially a directory to be created empty) may be associated with a device like `/dev/sda`; this is called mounting.

Reading and writing is done as usual; applications will use the Unix system calls, or if using the shell you may use the redirection operators or specific tools. Usually a user "tom" who will typically have a home directory `/home/tom` will write to that directory or to subdirectories. By having the system administrator (automatically) mounted the device to that directory there's nothing specific to consider. The user "tom" will just write in (or read from) the directories where he has permissions; under his own home directory he is usually quite free.

Comment: Also, on FreeBSD, my internal drives start with `/dev/ada0` and my external drivers start with `/dev/da0`